# Monterey OSX. `const_defined?': uninitialized constant Fog::Rackspace::CDN (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, fog

I have recently upgraded my OS. from Big sur to Montery.
When I was running my ruby application I am getting an error with careerwave

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/provider.rb:48:in `const_defined?': uninitialized constant Fog::Rackspace::CDN (NameError)
```

Can you please help in this regard, there was no change in the Gemfile or Gemfile.lock.

```
/Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/provider.rb:48:in `const_defined?': uninitialized constant Fog::Rackspace::CDN (NameError)
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/provider.rb:48:in `service_klass'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/provider.rb:37:in `service'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/fog-rackspace-0.1.6/lib/fog/rackspace.rb:53:in `<module:Rackspace>'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/fog-rackspace-0.1.6/lib/fog/rackspace.rb:28:in `<module:Fog>'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/fog-rackspace-0.1.6/lib/fog/rackspace.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/fog-2.2.0/lib/fog.rb:42:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bundler/gems/carrierwave-ff89d6e1c055/lib/carrierwave/storage.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bundler/gems/carrierwave-ff89d6e1c055/lib/carrierwave.rb:78:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/code/pwm/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.11.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.11.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.11.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.11.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.11.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/rajesh.banoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.11.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to include `https://github.com/fog/fog-rackspace` gem also. `fog-core` gem doesnt have code for `Rackspace`.